# Spring Integration JDBC Insert Statement

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm new to Spring integration. I'm trying to write a POJO for my database. I'm getting this error, which I don't quite understand. Is my syntax wrong, or am I using channels/adapters/gateways in the wrong manner?

> no declaration can be found for element `int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter`.

Here is my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"
    xmlns:int-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:int-ftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp/spring-integration-ftp.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway id="transmissionGateway"
    query="insert into MSRB_RTRS (Sec_ID, SourceLoad_ID, TradeDate) values (:Sec_ID, 
    :SourceLoad_ID, :TradeDate)"
    data-source="rmsa">

</int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>
```

```
public interface DatabaseService {
    public void insertMessage(int secID, int sourceLoadID, String tradeDate);
}
```

---

```
@Inject
DatabaseService service;

service.insertMessage(-1, -1, "20170830");
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.8112.100</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.companyname</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.COMMON-SBCOMMON-14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- End -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.companyname</groupId>
        <artifactId>companyname-spring-core-spring-4</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-M20160505-01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The spring integration jdbc pom contains

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>19.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring Integration but your error message appears to be derived from spring not "understanding" what int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter is. Silly question, but do you have the Spring-Integration available in your CLASSPATH? If your using Maven, check your pom.xml to ensure its there.

Comment: I believe it is, I'll post my deps

Comment: Just a note you are mixing versions of Spring which is never a good idea. You should use `dependencyManagement` in the POM with the Springframework BOM to make sure dependencies are as expected. 

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-maven-bom

Comment: You need to show your preamble (stuff at the top of the XML file); perhaps you haven't properly defined the `int-jdbc` namespace?

Comment: I've added the preamble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> spring-integration-jdbc-2.2.xsd

Don't put a version on the schema import. It has to match the version you are using (4.3).

If you leave the version off, Spring will resolve the right version for you (see `/META-INF/spring.schemas` in the jar).

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd
```

In any case; everything (jars, schema) must have matching versions.

Comment: That seems like good advice, but the change didn't resolve my issue.
Line 26 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/msrb/spring-int-jdbc.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 22; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-jdbc:outbound-gateway'

Comment: Is that a runtime error or a flag in your IDE? If the latter, ignore it or use a spring-aware IDE. If the former, there is still something wrong with your class path.

Comment: Runtime error :/. I'm using STS 3.7, which isn't flagging anything.

Comment: Are there any other things I'd need to include other than that Spring Integration JDBC pom? It's at the top of my maven dependency list, so nothing should be getting overridden.

Comment: And it fails when you run it from STS too? Edit your question to show your complete pom and the complete config file.

Comment: I've added some more detail

Comment: Remove `<type>pom</type>` from the `spring-integration-jdbc` dependency; you don't just want the pom, you need the whole jar.

Comment: That did it! Now it says "Configuration Problem: The 'request-channel' attribute is required for the top-level endpoint element: 'int-jdbc:outbound-gateway' with id='transmissionGateway'. I'm thinking that should be a separate Question?

Comment: Right - you need a request-channel. Outbound gateways receive requests via the channel and return replies. See the documentation and sample apps. Here's the [JDBC sample](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jdbc) it uses gateways.